# Error: Cannot find module 'asn1' when trying to run a node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am trying to run a Node.js app on an Azure app service with Node 8.1.4.

The app runs fine on my local machine.

I copied the entire app, including `node_modules`, to the Azure app service, but I get this:

```
Mon Sep 11 2017 07:52:14 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application 
has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Cannot find module 'asn1'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats\pem.js:9:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
```

This is coming from a package called sshpk. Here are its dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "asn1": "~0.2.3",
    "assert-plus": "^1.0.0",
    "bcrypt-pbkdf": "^1.0.0",
    "dashdash": "^1.12.0",
    "ecc-jsbn": "~0.1.1",
    "getpass": "^0.1.1",
    "jsbn": "~0.1.0",
    "tweetnacl": "~0.14.0"
  },
```

I checked and the `asn1` package is definitely there in the top-level `node_modules` folder. I also copied the `asn1` package into the `node_modules` which is inside `sshpk`, but it didn't help.

What can be the reason why this package is still not found? How can I troubleshoot this?

**Update**: tried running `npm cache clear` and `npm install -g npm` on the Azure server, nothing changed.

The entire top-level `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/datastore": "^1.1.0",
    "asn1": "^0.2.3",
    "async": "^2.1.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "documentdb": "^1.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "mssql": "^4.0.4",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal top-level `package.json` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AlexBlex added

Comment: Looks fine to me. Created an app w/o problems: `az webapp create --runtime "node|8.1" ...` The only thing I changed - removed "--inspect" from the start script.